# background-clip: text для IE?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, internet-explorer

Прочитав документацию, понял что IE вообще не поддерживает значение `text` у свойства `background-clip`.

Как быть, если нужен градиент сделать кроссбраузерно?

Делать весь алфавит в фотошопе и делать спрайт? Только так?

Comment: Если это логотип, к примеру, то можно разово его перевести в svg.

Comment: http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/

Answer (score 1):

Я недавно этим вопросом интересовался, вот [например](https://vostoksisters.github.io/) такую меню сварганил.
Посмотри код, он уже скомпилированный со всеми префиксами. Конкретно про IE, честно скажу, не знаю, но в Edge работает (а это не одно и то же?).
Код выглядит громоздким из-за псевдоэлемента, а в html нужно дополнительный атрибут пилить, но ведь градиентные тексты не так часто используются, так что хак вполне юзабельный)

```css
a
{
  font: bold 18pt sans-serif;
  color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

a::after
{
position: absolute;
content: attr(data-text);
left: 0;
top: 0;
text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(30%, #FF25D6), color-stop(80%, #ba00ff)) no-repeat;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF25D6 30%, #ba00ff 80%) no-repeat;
background: linear-gradient(#FF25D6 30%, #ba00ff 80%) no-repeat;
background-clip: text;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<a data-text="My funny text :)")>My funny text :)</a>
```